# Make SQL selection from nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a selection based on a nested array I get from a prior selection.

Here is where I make my first selection:

```
$coursequery = " 
            SELECT
                courseID
            FROM enrollments 
            WHERE 
                studentID = '$userid' 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($coursequery); 
            $result = $stmt->execute(); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

            $_SESSION['studentcourses'] = $rows;
```

This gets all the courseID's in the following format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [courseID] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [courseID] => 7 ) )
```

and I want to be able to access these ID's for selecting information from a different table. I've started by trying to use a for loop to grab all the "course information" depending on the ID.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $coursequery = " 
            SELECT
                *
            FROM courses 
            WHERE courseID = '$studentcourses[$i]'

        "; 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($coursequery); 
            $result = $stmt->execute(); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

            $_SESSION['studentcourseinfo'] = $row;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in accomplishing this!

Comment: Start with mysql `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with one SQL query thus eliminating all these loops

```
SELECT
    *
FROM courses
     INNER JOIN enrollments ON 
         enrollments.courseID = courses.courseID 
         AND enrollments.studentID = '$userid'
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use same array in query, can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) function

```
  $coursequery =  "SELECT  * FROM courses 
  WHERE courseID  IN (" . implode(",", $studentcourses) . ");";
```

As long as you change the output format

```
Array (6, 7)
```

where 6 and 7 would be the id of the courses

Also in you code have mistake in rewrite var `$_SESSION['studentcourseinfo'] = $row;` these overwriting the same variable at a time